# Google Geocoder Lookup get postal code by country and city

Tags: google-maps-api

I'm currently using Google Geocoder API to determine location data for my web service.
It's important for me to get the postal code for a given country and city, but it's look like that Google is limiting the result.

Here's the API call:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=deutschland,+saarlouis&language=de&sensor=false

The result is like that:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Saarlouis",
               "short_name" : "Saarlouis",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Landkreis Saarlouis",
               "short_name" : "Landkreis Saarlouis",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Saarland",
               "short_name" : "SL",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Deutschland",
               "short_name" : "DE",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Saarlouis, Deutschland",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.36187570,
                  "lng" : 6.815549499999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 49.26046930,
                  "lng" : 6.67501510
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 49.31346060,
               "lng" : 6.752286499999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.36187570,
                  "lng" : 6.815549499999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 49.26046930,
                  "lng" : 6.67501510
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you don't get the postal code is the query is too broad. If you would add a street name to the query the result will contain a postal code. A solution to your problem if you don't have a street name or don't want to use it is to split the geocoding into two parts:

Step 1: Use the city to get the GPS coordinates

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=amsterdam

Step 2: Use the the GPS coordidates to get the postal code

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.3182742,4.7288558

---

For those doing it in backend/script, here is a snippet: (using python [Geocoder](https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/))

```
g = geocoder.google(city, key=google_api_key)
latlng = g.latlng
g_prime = geocoder.google("{},{}".format(*latlng), key=google_api_key)
postal_code = g_prime.postal
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the **Official Drag Markers Geocoder** - you have German Postcodes displayed.

[image]

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html

(zoom to Germany or change the source code and set the bounds to Germany)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Geocoding API has usage limits.

> Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of **2,500
>   geolocation requests per day**. (User of Google Maps API for Business
>   may perform up to **100,000 requests per day**.) This limit is enforced to
>   prevent abuse and/or repurposing of the Geocoding API, and this limit
>   may be changed in the future without notice. Additionally, we enforce
>   a request rate limit to prevent abuse of the service. If you exceed
>   the 24-hour limit or otherwise abuse the service, the Geocoding API
>   may stop working for you temporarily. If you continue to exceed this
>   limit, your access to the Geocoding API may be blocked.

You might want to try setting up your own geocoder using [Gisgraphy](http://www.gisgraphy.com/) or something similar. That way you won't be affected by usage limits.

Comment: Oh yes, i read about that. I played around with Gisgraphy for an alternative to Google's services. Gisgraphy looks great but the also for areas of big cities in Germany there are no postal codes.

Comment: How many requests are you making? You might want to track that. Or use Google Maps API for Business.

Comment: Currently my problem is not to be limited by maximal requests per day (for the free version). I'm just wondering why google doesn't tell me the postal code for a location. But thank you about your hint about request limitation :-)